# How to change the orientation of a view controller for specific view

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have following requirement in my application.

- A tableView with games title
- After selecting a game / cell
- A detail view appears
- when user presses on a button to see the huge image from detail screen, it should push another view
- a new pushed view should be displayed in landscape mode

All previous view should be in portrait mode & only the last image displaying view controller should be in landscape mode.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here [How can I displat one uiview in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356882/how-can-i-display-one-uiview-in-landscape)