# Screen orientation in ViewController that doesn't have a navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an iOS 6 iPad app where most of ViewControllers have their Navigation Controller. In all these views I want the orientation to be only landscape, which works just fine. There is one View Controller though which does not have a Navigation Controller - I just open its view on top of Navigation Controller's top View Controller, but it's not a modal. I do want the user to be able to change screen's orientation on that View Controller, but keep landscape on all the rest of them. This is what I do:

Navigation Controller's subclass:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation);
}
```

And here are the same methods for the particular View Controller that I want to have both landscape and portrait:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Since this View Controller doesn't have a Navigation Controller I was sure that this would solve the issue. However for some reason I'm still not able to flip the screen in this View Controller. Here is the way I show that View Controller - maybe this is the reason behind this:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
[[window.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:previewView];
```

Comment: I figured that the way I show this view has to be a reason behind this, so my question here would rather be is it possible to have these views have separate orientation configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact , the way you show this special view controller make your view unable to change orientation , because when device change orientation , it ask your key window's rootController whether it can orientate or not , and in your situation , you return landscape so your window only support landscape mode.

So maybe you should present it from your navigationController without animation . than implement `- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` in your special view controller.

Further reading: [Understand ViewController Orientation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW5)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
 }
```

Change this to

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

If you have more doubts
```

refer This 
[How can I display one UIView in landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356882/how-can-i-display-one-uiview-in-landscape)

Comment: @jahsiotr Change this in view controller where you want change the orientation

Comment: Wouldn't this block that View Controller from changing the orientation? What I need is to let user change orientation on that 1 particular View Controller and don't let on all the rest of them